# Where to set references to null, if references are passed by value in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

The following code constructs 2 linkedlists and passes both of them to construct a 3rd merged linkedlist. However once merged, the l1 and l2 ( initially constructed ) linkedlist have changed.  Where in this peice of code should l1 and l2 be set to null ?

EDIT: The reason for setting it to null is we dont want client to use a modified l1 or l2 in future. We want to have a clear contract that once merged, we have a fresh new reference and previous references were made null and void so that someone does not use them believing they were linkedlists at time time of their construction.

```
public class MergeLinkedList {
    Node first;
    Node last;

    public void add (int val) {
        final Node l = last;
        final Node newNode = new Node(val, null);
        last = newNode;
        if (first == null) {
            first = newNode;
        } else {
            l.next = newNode;
        }
    }

    public void displayList() {
        Node tempFirst = first;
        while (tempFirst != null) {
            System.out.print(tempFirst.item + " ");
            tempFirst = tempFirst.next;
        }
    }

    private static class Node {
        int item;
        Node next;

        Node(int element, Node next) {
            this.item = element;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    private Node mergeLinkedListRecursive(Node list1, Node list2) {
        if (list1 == null) {
           return list2; 
        }

        if (list2 == null) {
            return list1;
        }

        if (list1.item < list2.item) {
            list1.next = mergeLinkedListRecursive(list1.next, list2);
            return list1;
        } else {
            list2.next = mergeLinkedListRecursive(list1, list2.next);
            return list2;
        }
    }

    public void mergeLinkedListRecursion(MergeLinkedList list1, MergeLinkedList list2) {
        first = mergeLinkedListRecursive(list1.first, list2.first);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a1 = {1, 3, 5};
        int[] a2 = {2, 4};

        MergeLinkedList l1 = new MergeLinkedList();
        for (int val : a1 ) {
            l1.add(val); 
        }

        MergeLinkedList l2 = new MergeLinkedList();
        for (int val : a2) {
            l2.add(val);
        }

        MergeLinkedList l3 = new MergeLinkedList();
        l3.mergeLinkedListRecursion(l1, l2);
        l3.displayList();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by setting l1 and l2 as null?

Answer (score 2):

*The onus of correct usage of the objects named by `l1` and `l2` is on the caller*.

That is, while the caller might assume that `l1` and `l2` always evaluate to the same sequence of items, after `l3.mergeLinkedListRecursion(l1, l2);` this is not the case. This is because the method *performs side effects and mutates the objects*.

After the method invocation *it is up to the caller to ensure correct usage of `l1` and `l2`*. The "correct" usage would likely be to not use them at all. (The `l1` and `l2` variables still evaluate to heads of two lists, one being a sub-list; just not what might be expected.)

*Even if it were possible to assign the arguments (`l1` and `l2`) to null - i.e. with call-by-reference semantics - it would be impossible to ensure that all variables/fields evaluating to said (now mutated) objects were assigned null*.

*A variable/field is a name for a particular object*: how is it possible to track down all the names for a given object, say Soda - or is it Pop? Cola? Coke? 코카인?

One way to prevent this issue is to use *immutable* lists; in this case the merged list would actually contain all *new* nodes and not intertwining existing nodes - that is, with an immutable list, `next` can *only* be set in the constructor. Some languages like Haskell and Scala follow this approach.

Another approach (which I hesitate to suggest) would be to make a "container container"; for a linked list it could simply be a "dummy head node" whose `next` would be assigned to null when an operation was performed on the list that "made it invalid". However, I find this a hackish and uneeded solution that is hard to implement correctly and dirties up an otherwise a simple mutable linked-list implementation.

The fundamental problem is *mutations and side-effects* and is just one of the ugly aspects of writing non-pure code - a little bit of documentation (and reading of such) can go a long way. Also, Unit Tests: testing can catch problems that might arise from incorrect assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you would want to set l1 and l2 to null, but to do it you would need to put it after this line:

```
l3.mergeLinkedListRecursion(l1, l2);
```

Why exactly do you want them to be set to null?

Answer (score 0):

If a `Node` object becomes invalid after being used as an argument to `mergeLinkedListRecursive()`, then this is something a node should remember:

```
class Node {
    ...
    boolean valid = true;
    void markInvalid() { valid = false; }
}
```

And then in `mergeLinkedListRecursive()` mark them as such:

```
list1.markInvalid();
list2.markInvalid();
```

And of course, make `Node`'s methods first verify that it is in a valid state.

Comment: This will fail in many cases (and on the provided data) because the same nodes are mutated. The result would be that `l3.valid -> false`.

Comment: @user2246674 that's a good point, thanks for pointing it out. Leaving my answer here, though, because I think that in general invalidation should be done on the *object* level, not the reference level, and that's the message I'm trying to provide.